# Getting data from database to angular js

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs, http

I'm new to Angular JS and I've been learning from codeschool.

I have this problem i can't figure out how to solve: I want to get data from a PHP file that I'm working on but first I wanted to make a short example because something just doesn't make sense to me, and is that can never retrieve the information that has the PHP file to the angular controller.

I have uploaded it on a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcguarinpenaranda/azT5q/8/)** you can check out if you want.

Here's the html, it's pretty basic:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MyController as c">
         <h1>{{c.title}}</h1>
        <p>Controller trial: {{c.content}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here the JavaScript source:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("MyController", ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.title = "My Title";
    var filecontent = "Data should be replaced";
    $http.get("http://www.otherwise-studios.com/example.php")
        .success(function (data) {
            filecontent = data;
            //I don't know why data is not loaded here :S
        });
    this.content = filecontent;
}]);
```

Finally, this is the output i'm getting:

```
My Title

Controller trial: Data should be replaced
```

If you visit the **[link](http://www.otherwise-studios.com/example.php)** from which i'm retrieving the information you should see this output "You connected to my PHP file", but as i said before, the data seems to never get updated to the variable:

```
this.content
```

Thank you so much for all your help!

Juan Camilo Guarin P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data isn't loaded here, because initially "content" is primitive.
You have two ways: init "content" as object or write smth like this:

```
var filecontent = "la la la",
    that = this;

$http.get("http://www.otherwise-studios.com/example.php")
    .success(function (data) {
        that.content = data;
    });
```

Comment: Actually, i went with this one because i didn't want to touch the scope yet. Maybe in a future i will be using scope.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.controller("MyController", ['$http', '$scope'  function ($http,$scope) {
this.title = "My Title";
var filecontent = "Data should be replaced";
$http.get("http://www.otherwise-studios.com/example.php")
    .success(function (data) {
        filecontent = data;
        $scope.content = filecontent; // must be within success function to automatically call $apply
    });

}]);
```

Comment: You're wrong.
"this.title" binds to controller, not to scope. :)

Comment: Thank you so much, i tested your answer and it worked :)